# Cannot execute an sqlite SQL file to create a database

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have an sql (text file) with a long transaction to create a database.

I am using Kompex sqlite c++ library for this:

```
// open database
Kompex::SQLiteDatabase *pDatabase = new Kompex::SQLiteDatabase(CT2A(strDBFilename), SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, 0);

// create statement instance for sql queries/statements
Kompex::SQLiteStatement *pStmt = new Kompex::SQLiteStatement(pDatabase);

strSQLCreateDB=get_file_contents(strSQLFilename).c_str(); // load the SQL file

try {
    pStmt->Sql(strSQLCreateDB);
    pStmt->ExecuteAndFree();        
} catch(Kompex::SQLiteException &exception)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception Occured" << std::endl;
    exception.Show();
}

pDatabase->Close();
```

The database is created with 0 bytes and no errors.
I am interested in any sample code even without the kompex library, to execute this sql transaction which creates the db.

executing the database from sqlite browser creates the database without errors.

this is a part of the SQL command file

```
/* Disable Foreign Keys */
pragma foreign_keys = off;
/* Begin Transaction */
begin transaction;

/* Database [scanlog(1)] */
pragma auto_vacuum=0;
pragma encoding='UTF-8';
pragma page_size=1024;

/* Drop table [ApplicationNames] */
drop table if exists [ApplicationNames];

/* Table structure [ApplicationNames] */
CREATE TABLE [ApplicationNames] (
  [Id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [ApplicationName] TEXT, 
  [Icon] TEXT);
CREATE INDEX [IndexApps] ON [ApplicationNames] ([Id], [ApplicationName]);

/* Data [ApplicationNames] */
insert into [ApplicationNames] values(1, 'Windows System', null);
insert into [ApplicationNames] values(2, 'Internet Explorer', null); 
insert into [ApplicationNames] values(3, 'Google Chrome', null);

/* Commit Transaction */
commit transaction;

/* Enable Foreign Keys */
pragma foreign_keys = on;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
// open connection to a DB
    if (SQLITE_OK != (ret = sqlite3_open_v2(CT2A(strDBFilename), &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL)))
    {
        TRACE("Failed to open SQLite conn: %d\n", ret);
        break;
    } 

    // prepare the statement
    if (SQLITE_OK != (ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, CT2A(strSQLCreateDB), -1, &query, NULL)))
    {
        TRACE("Failed to prepare SQLite script: %d, %s\n", ret, sqlite3_errmsg(pDb));
        break;
    }

    if (SQLITE_OK != (ret=sqlite3_exec(pDb, CT2A(strSQLCreateDB), NULL, 0, NULL)))
    {
        TRACE("Failed to execute SQLite script: %d, %s\n", ret, sqlite3_errmsg(pDb));
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `Sql` and `sqlite3_prepare` functions execute only the *first* SQL command in the string.

To execute multiple commands in a string, you must use `sqlite3_exec`:

```
if (SQLITE_OK != (ret = sqlite3_open_v2(CT2A(strDBFilename), &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL)))
{
    TRACE("Failed to open SQLite conn: %d\n", ret);
    break;
} 

if (SQLITE_OK != (ret = sqlite3_exec(pDb, CT2A(strSQLCreateDB), NULL, 0, NULL)))
{
    TRACE("Failed to execute SQLite script: %d, %s\n", ret, sqlite3_errmsg(pDb));
    break;
}
```

Comment: What include do I need for the `CT2A()` function and what does it do? I had to use `strDBFilename.c_str()` because I had `std::string` in my case. Also, you might want to denote that `strSQLCreateDB` is a string of SQL statements, not a file name to create. That wasn't apparent at first to me.

Comment: @Volomike All this stuff comes from the question's code.

Answer (score 0):

`view.sql` have the statement

Take database definition from file, this way is easy to manage the definition of tables, views, and triggers:

```
{
    std::ifstream ifs("view.sql");
    std::string content(
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),        
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())
    );

    size_t n_pos,o_pos=0;
    n_pos = content.find(";");
    while (n_pos!=content.npos) {
        ++n_pos;
        sqlite::execute(con,content.substr(o_pos,n_pos-o_pos).c_str(),true);
        o_pos=n_pos;
        n_pos= content.find(";",o_pos);
    }
}
sqlite::execute(con,"VACUUM;",true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.